# GLSL only render fragments with Z-position between uniforms minZ and maxZ

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a mesh with many thousands of vertices. The model represents a complex structure that needs to be visualized both in its entirety but also in part. The user of my application should be able to define a minimum and maximum value for the Z-Axis. Only fragments with a position between these limits should be rendered.

My naive solution would be to write a Fragment shader somewhat like this:

```
#extension GL_EXT_texture_array : enable

    uniform sampler2DArray m_ColorMap;
    uniform float m_minZ;
    uniform float m_maxZ;

    in vec4 fragPosition;
    in vec3 texCoord;

void main(){
    if (fragPosition.z < m_minZ || fragPosition.z > m_maxZ) {
        discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = texture2DArray(m_ColorMap, texCoord);
}
```

Alternatively I could try to somehow filter out vertices in the vertex shader. Perhaps by setting their position values to (0,0,0,0) if they fall out of range.

I am fairly certain both of these approaches can work. But **I would like to know if there is some better way of doing this** that I am not aware of. Some kind of standard approach for slicing models along an axis.

Please keep in mind that I do not want to use separate VBO's for each slice since they can be set dynamically by the user.

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you use perspective ... the perspective matrix already does this for you ...

Comment: I want to filter based on the untransformed positions. The model should be sliced along its own Z-axis, not the Z-axis of world-space.

Comment: then simply convert visible z range to NDC `<-1,+1>` or `<0,-1>` or `<-1,0>` range depending on the pipeline settings and  the GL implementation will cut of the rest using depth test on its own ... no need for discard

Comment: You mean I do that on Client side re-uploading the buffer? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: You can do it in Vertex shader ... by simple linear interpolation ...

Comment: Can you give an example of what that would look like? I don't think I fully understand what you mean by that.

Comment: you got input vertex `p` and want output vertex `q` so you just do `q.x=p.x; q.y=p.y;` and `q.z=z0+(z1-z0)*(p.z-znear)/(zfar-znear)` where `z0,z1` is the new range of z... I am not sure if gl is clipping from `<-1,+1>` or `<0,+1>` or `<-1,0>` so just try which one works... with `DEPTH_TEST` on

Comment: What you are saying is that I change the gl_Position output, correct? But that would change the way the model is rendered and I don't want that. The rendered positions of all vertices should be unchanged.

Comment: you are rendering just x,y they are unchanged if you need also unchanged z in fragment (for some computations) then pass it as another out variable from vertex to fragment ...

Comment: Oh I understand now, that makes sense. I am going to try it out and get back to you. Is there a way to get the values of z-near and z-far with a build-in function? Otherwise I will have to do it with uniforms.

Comment: They are not in GLSL ... `znear` and `zfar` are just parameters for Projection matrix creation and can be extracted from those (the matrix itself will do the interpolation on its own but that one is non linear)... but if you are not using perspective projection then use uniforms ...  I would use uniforms in both cases as extracting from perspective will add some more math operations slowing down the stuff a bit which is unnecessary ...